# How to combine similar properties into subclass?

Tags: c#

UPDATE:
I had to rewrite question from ground...

I want to create a class/object, which has a nice structure, where I can group similar types of sub-objects, like

```
public class World{ 
    public class myStrings {
       public String a {get;set;}
       public String b {get;set;}
       public String c {get;set;}
       //.... 
    }
    public class myDoubles {
       public Double a {get;set;}
       public Double b {get;set;}
       public Double c {get;set;}
       //.... 
    }
    .....
}
```

later, i my code, I initialise that object

```
World x = new World();
```

and can set/get any property of it with:

```
x.direct_child_property = ....
```

however, i cant set/get

`x.myStrings.a = ...    //gives error`

How to achieve to set/get those properties easily ? should i change it to static? (otherwise it is annoying to initialise individual objects for each sub-class)..

Comment: That is not how c# works. I believe you need to familiarize yourself with the language more.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Agree with @Nkosi. There are ways to do what you are asking, but the correct approach depends on the problem you're trying to solve

Comment: You would have to initialize that sub-class into a property variable before you can use it.

Comment: @Nkosi you are right, i have rewriten whole question.

Comment: a nested class is just like other class that you have to initialize. so `x.myStrings.a` has no meaning unless you have actual property of type `myStrings` inside your `World` class. and you should use that property.

Comment: You need to either make those classes static, or instantiate them somewhere.

Comment: Can you not just use a collection (e.g. array or list)?

Comment: @RufusL thanks, one question: as i know static properties becomes globally accessible, but in this case, it remains static only in instantianted parent object-variable, right? and thus, when i insantinte parent object within another new variable, then it wont interfere, right? wow, thanks.

Comment: In the future, once a question has answers, and you find you need to reword the whole question, it would be best to just delete the original questions and post a new one.  That way answers to the original questions don't clutter up the new question.

Comment: No, that's totally wrong. static classes are always static. so they are always one. @T.Todua if you have them inside non-static classes, it will be still one for all instances.

Comment: `static` means it doesn't require an instance to have a value, but does not change accessibility. That is controlled through `private`, `public`, etc

Comment: If at all possible, it a real-world example would help folks understand what you're doing. `World.myStrings.a` does not exactly describe what you're doing or how the class would be consumed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should adjust your approach and use a collection instead of having so many strings:

```
public class World
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> MyStrings = new Dictionary<string, string> ();
    public Dictionary<string, double> MyDoubles = new Dictionary<string, double> ();
    public string GetString(string key)
    {
        if (MyStrings.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return MyStrings[key];
        }
        return "";
    }
    public double GetDouble(string key)
    {
        if (MyDoubles.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return MyDoubles[key];
        }
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

Then when you use it:

```
World x = new World();
x.MyStrings["a"] = "A String";
x.MyDoubles["a"] = 3.14;
string someString = x.GetString("a");
double someDouble = x.GetDouble("a");
```

If you are concerned about using the string names everywhere, define constants.  If you have a set number of values that never changes, you could use fixed collections like arrays and define constants for the index.  The dictionary allows more flexibility as your list changes.

Comment: This solution swaps build errors and fast code with run time errors and slower code (since the values must be looked up).  It also does not properly show how to access the values in the dictionary.

Comment: Dictionary lookup is really fast and as mentioned, constants can be used to avoid build errors.  I'll update to show ways to use it.

Comment: Dictionary is fast, but not as fast as direct property access.

Comment: @Trisped It's very unlikely that there's any performance issue here that you need to worry about. .NET Dictionary lookup is very, very fast.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of the sub-class:

```
public class World{ 
    public class myStrings {
        public String a {get;set;}
        public String b {get;set;}
        public String c {get;set;}
        //.... 
    }
    public class myDoubles {
        public Double a {get;set;}
        public Double b {get;set;}
        public Double c {get;set;}
        //.... 
    }
    public myStrings Strings {get;set;}
    public myDoubles Doubles {get;set;}
}
```

Then:

```
World x = new World();
x.Strings = new myStrings();
x.Strings.a = ...
x.Doubles = new myDoubles();
x.Doubles.a = ...
```

Comment: @T.Todua I have rewritten my answer to match your question rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options, which to use depends a lot on what you're trying to do:

1. Make the `abc` property static.

   ```
   public class WorldA {
       public class Animals{
           public static string abc { get; set; }
       } 
   }

   WorldA.Animals.abc = "foo";
   ```
2. Create an instance of `Animals` inside of the `World` class and then reference it from the `x` instance you created.

   ```
   public class WorldB {
       public Animals animals = new Animals();
       public class Animals{
           public string abc { get; set; }
       }
   }

   WorldB b = new WorldB();
   b.animals.abc = "foo";
   ```

   If you use this method you won't be able to have the same name for the class and the property.

Comment: @T.Todua the answer remains the same.  You can't reference `myStrings` (a class definition) from an _instance_ of `World`.

Comment: btw, i get error at line: `....= new Animals();`  with your above code

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Work
{
    public string ABC { get; set; }
    public Animal Animal { get; set; }
}
public class Animal
{
    public string ABC { get; set; }
}
```

Then to use

```
World _world = new World();
//this'll work
_world.ABC = "something";
//Initiate new animal
_world.Animal = new Animal();
//Now this'll work too
_world.Animal.ABC = "value";
```

In other words, in order to assign a value to the _world's Animal property you need to first assign an Animal() object to it.

Comment: I noticed that. The same principle applies. In your new question, you need to assign an instance to direct_child_property. So x.direct_child_property = new type_of_direct_child_property(). Then you'll be able to access it by x.direct_child_property.some_propert = "value". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> (otherwise it is annoying to initialise individual objects for each sub-class)..

Its not, you can initialize your properties by default value.

I suggest you to not declare your classes nested. you will be fine. making classes nested just complicates the way you access it.

```
public class World{ 
    public MyDoubles MyDoubles { get; set; } = new MyDoubles(); // initialized by default
    public MyStrings MyStrings { get; set; } = new MyStrings(); // initialized by default
    .....
}

public class MyDoubles {
   public Double a {get;set;}
   public Double b {get;set;}
   public Double c {get;set;}
   //.... 
}

public class MyStrings {
   public String a {get;set;}
   public String b {get;set;}
   public String c {get;set;}
   //.... 
}
```

Now you can do

```
x.MyStrings.a = "";
```

Comment: no, nested is needed in my specific case, because they are one objects. many thanks anyway!

Comment: having classes nested doesn't make it one object, they will be individual objects, so here there will be 3 objects whether they are nested or not. @T.Todua by the way you can have them nested, this solution will still work for you. just name properties something different than class name.

Comment: @T.Todua From your question it appears that you don't fully understand what nested classes are, so it's not clear that you really need them. Can you explain why you see that as a requirement?